# Complex merging in R with duplicate matching values in y set producing problems

Tags: r, merge

So I'm trying to merge two dataframes. Dataframe x looks something like:

```
Name     ParentID
Steve    1
Kevin    1
Stacy    1
Paula    4
Evan     7
```

Dataframe y looks like:

```
ParentID   OtherStuff
1          things
2          stuff
3          item
4          ideas
5          short
6          help
7          me
```

The dataframe I want would look like:

```
Name     ParentID   OtherStuff
Steve    1          things
Kevin    1          things
Stacy    1          things
Paula    4          ideas
Evan     7          me
```

Using a left merge gives me substantially more observations than I want, with many duplicates. Any idea how to merge things, where y is duplicated where appropriate to match x?

I'm working with a databases set up similarly to the example. x has 5013 observations, while y has 6432. Using the merge function as described by Joel and thelatemail gives me 1627727 observations.

Comment: `merge(x,y)` works for me, as does `dplyr's`  `left_join(x,y)` and `data.table`'s `y[x, on="ParentID"]` for the example given. Am I missing some other level of complexity here?

Comment: just a simple simple inner join `merge(x,y, by = "ParentID")`

Comment: I'm working with a databases set up similarly to the example. x has 5013 observations, while y has 6432. Using the merge function as described by Joel and thelatemail gives me 1627727 observations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` from `base R`

```
df1$OtherStuff <- with(df1, df2$OtherStuff[match(ParentID, df2$ParentID)])
df1
#   Name ParentID OtherStuff
#1 Steve        1     things
#2 Kevin        1     things
#3 Stacy        1     things
#4 Paula        4      ideas
#5  Evan        7         me
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. Thanks!